# Chrome pdf viewer download when opening new tab using post request

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, web, attachment

I have a requirement to display a pdf in a new browser tab, and the file should be retrieved by doing a post request to the server.

The client is opening the new tab passing it in a form as bellow:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.target = "_blank";
form.method = "POST";
form.action = url;
form.style.display = "none";

for (var key in data) {
    if(!data[key]) continue;
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = key;
    input.value = data[key];
    form.appendChild(input);
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

Server side is returning the header 'Content-Disposition' with value 'inline; filename*=UTF-8''filename.pdf'.

When the new tab is displayed on chrome, the pdf can be visualized normally, but the download doesnt work (receive an error that the endpoint is not reachable).

If I change the method to 'GET' I can see the pdf file and download it, but for security reasons the parameters should be sent over a post request. Changing the content type to attachment makes the post request downloads the file correctly.

Any idea what could be cause this and how to fix it?